# Can I draw a part of image out side boundary to the opposite side of screen?

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader

[image]

I want to render image like this picture. If an image goes over to the right boundary, it appears from the left.
Can I do this with shader? or should I have to check boundary and draw twice?